# Add appointment date to WooCommerce orders tab (frontend)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, jet-engine

I am using JetAppoitment (crocoblock) to make services bookable.
I would like to add the appoitment date to the orders from the front-end side.

Here is the code I used :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function add_account_orders_column( $columns ){
$columns['custom-column'] = __( 'Date de livraison', 'woocommerce' );

return $columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 
'add_account_orders_column_rows' );
function add_account_orders_column_rows( $order ) {
// Example with a custom field
if ( $value = $order->get_meta( '_appointment_date' ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $value );
}
}
```

The first part of the code worked good, the extra column is here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSLiq.png

The problem is I have no data...

Any idea to how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column',
        'add_account_orders_column_rows');

function add_account_orders_column_rows($order) {
// Example with a custom field
    if ($value = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_appointment_date')) {
        echo esc_html($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doens't work :(

Comment: Then confirm the meta key is correct, checking orders ids have the meta values in the database.

Comment: here is what I tried but it displays the order date. The error is at the end of the code ($data[0]['date']). Any idea about how to fix it ?

`add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-date', 'add_order_date_orders_column_rows', 9999 );  
function add_order_date_orders_column_rows( $order ) {  
  
 if ( $value = get_post_meta($order->get_ID(), '_jet_apb_wc_details', true)['form_data']['appointment_date'] ) { 
  $data = json_decode($value, true);
  echo esc_html( date('d/m/Y', $data[0]['date'] ));
 } 
}`

Comment: dump $data and check if it contains the expected result

Comment: already tried, it displays today's date